Values are not displayed while debugging in VS2022
I couldn't able to see the values of variables while debugging. In watch window its showing however while moving the mouse pointer over the variables the values are not displaying. I didn't have the problems in earlier VS versions and this problem is happening only for few variables not for all, Refer attached snaps



I have tried on deleting vs files and changed properties framework versions as suggested on other threads related to this question but nothing helped me.

Hi , please try to enable Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls in Tools > Options > Debugging > General to see if the values are displayed.

doube z = x * y + y *x;
Bm1.GetCordinateSystem().Axisx

It seems the two values  x * y and Axisx are different type. The x* y is a double number and Axisx is a property of Bm1.
For this issue, please check the Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls in Tools > Options > Debugging > General. Try to enable this setting to see if the issue persists.
If the issue persists, please try to reset your settings from Tools->Import and Export settings.
Hope it can help you.

Axisx appears to be a property on whatever type GetCoordinateSystem() returns.
